# Unable to add filter for groupby function in bar chart

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a bar chart which looks like this:

```
df.groupby(['age'])['no_show'].count().plot(kind='bar');
```

[image]

The problem is that I need to filter the age to make the chart more readable. In this case, something like age<30. How do I add this filter into the code in order to reflect in the chart?

Comment: `df.groupby('age')['no_show'].count().loc[:30].plot.bar()` would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter before you group:

```
df[df.age < 30].groupby(['age'])['no_show'].count().plot(kind='bar');
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks